# Problem with starting Hyperledger Network

Tags: docker, installation, hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem with Hyperledger Fabric.
I want to set up a hyperledger fabric network and I installed all Prerequisites and installed all binaries, samples and docker images

Here is the tutorial:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#install-prerequisites
However, when I run the command
./byfn.sh generate 
it says : cryptogen tool not found. exiting

Comment: can you pls confirm if you have cryptogen binary in bin folder and your script is able to access it. Did you run the script for downloading pre requisite? if yes, then did you run it as sudo? You can try using following command and see if it works -- ../bin/cryptogen generate config=./crypto-config.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Soufian Kaddouri welcome to Stackoverflow

Problem is cryptogen tool is not present under path

Please complete below article

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

curl command which is present in above article, will get all necessary stuff and it set fabric-samples/bin to your path

However, if it missed then follow below instructions!!

cd fabric-samples/bin

issue `pwd` command and copy the result

nano ~/.bashrc

Add below line to your bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:{paste pwd result here}/fabric-samples/bin
```

source ~/.bashrc

just issue cryptogen from new terminal it should issue below result

```
usage: cryptogen [<flags>] <command> [<args> ...]

Utility for generating Hyperledger Fabric key material

Flags:
  --help  Show context-sensitive help (also try --help-long and --help-man).

Commands:
  help [<command>...]
    Show help.

  generate [<flags>]
    Generate key material

  showtemplate
    Show the default configuration template

  version
    Show version information

  extend [<flags>]
    Extend existing network
```

Now Proceed with ./byfn.sh

Comment: thank u for ur answer it works now, but another problem showed up. 
After I run "./byfn.sh generate" I run the command "./byfn.sh up" I get this error "Error: No such container: cli
ERROR !!!! Test failed
"